# Access Violation no Código

Tags: delphi

Senhores, tenho este código, ele se situa no meu `Form Activate`, então, ele serve para identificar o meu software que está rodando, e consequentemente atualizá-lo, ou seja, é um auto atualizador.

```
if servidor = false then   //se o servidor estiver conectado
        begin
          for i := 0 to ParamCount  do      //contador para verificar os parametros
            begin
              if vparam[i] <> ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName) then <---Acess Violation aqui!
                begin
                ........
                end;
            end;
         end;
```

No comentário indica a linha do Acess Violation, alguém poderia me dizer por quê?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar `for i := 0 to (ParamCount -1) do` uma vez que se a quantidade de parâmetros for 5, você terá que iterar de 0 a 4 (ou seja, 5 iterações). Da maneira que está você está iterando de  0 a 5 (6 iterações), assim ocorrerá access violation.

Comment: Ainda continua dando o erro.... :S

Comment: O access violation ocorre na primeira execução da linha de código? Este array possui de fato a quantidade de posições necessárias? Esse erro muito provavelmente indica que você está tentandoa acessar dentro de "vparam" uma posição inexistente...

Comment: Provavemnte @Arthurdeandrade, tem uma função que determina o tamanho do array, estou verificando agora.

Comment: Não está dando mais acess violation amigo, obrigado.

Comment: Antes de sair, tem como da uma explicada para que serve esse `ParamCount`? Obrigado

Comment: O ParamCount simplesmente contém o número de parâmetros que foram usados para invocar o executável na abertura do mesmo. Assim se você passar como parâmetros na abertura, por exemplo, o nome do servidor, o usuário, e o nível de permissão, o valor do ParamCount será 3.

Comment: Saquei, muito obrigado amigo.